# How do I match all text after a regex capture group but only up to the next repeated match?

Tags: python, regex

I have some irregular text that I need to form into a python dictionary:

`S5=test 3,300 Plus,S6=test 2 7,999-1,900,S7=test 3,899-1,500,S8=test 4,599-1,300,S9=Test 5-1,399,`

I'm looking to grab everything before the `=` sign as the **key** and everything *after* the `=` sign but *before* the next **key** as the **value**.

This is what I have so far in python but it doesn't seem to be working for cases with multiple `,` commas:

`(\w*)=+((?<==).+?(?=,))+`

https://regex101.com/r/Tokjsw/2

Any ideas or simpler regex expressions would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(\w+)=(.+?)(?=,\w+=|$)
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tokjsw/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\w+)`: Match key with 1+ word characters
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `(.+?)`: Match value with 1+ of any character that satisfies next lookahead condition
- `(?=,\w+=|$)`: Make sure that value is followed by a comma, key and `=` or end of line